# About the resolution of pdf.js in pdfviewer

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am a newbie to pdfviewer, and have some problems about how to set resolution of the context via pdf.js, the following is my code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PDFJS.getDocument('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
        for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum < pdf.numPages; ++pageNum) {
            pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(function (page) {
                // you can now use *page* here

                var scale = 2;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);

                document.getElementById('pdf-container').appendChild(canvas);
            });
        }
    })

</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div> 
      <div id="pdf-container"></div>
</form>
```

the main problem is the resolution of the page is low, make the content not clean, unlike the view in 
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html. How to set the resolution to make it like viewer by using pdf.js. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make the resolution better, but I didn't find out a math equation to represent that.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        PDFJS.getDocument('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
            for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum < pdf.numPages; ++pageNum) {
                pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(function (page) {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.style.height = "1000px";
                    canvas.style.width = "900px";
                    var scale = 2.5;
                    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;
                    console.log("canvas.height=" + canvas.height);
                    console.log("canvas.width=" + canvas.width);
                    console.log("canvas.style.height=" + canvas.style.height);
                    console.log("canvas.style.width=" + canvas.style.width);
                    console.log("scale="+scale);
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    page.render(renderContext);
                    document.getElementById('pdf-container').appendChild(canvas);
                });
            }
        })

    </script>
```

set the style of width and height of canvas the static value, and then using scale of getViewport, set the width and height of canvas. In this situation, the dpi of the context will be better, and if the scale is higher, the dpi will be more improved.

Comment: I find out a math equation to represent that. I think canvas.height/canvas.style.height is the quality of DPI. And the more the ratio it is, and the higher resolution it will be.